# Amazon EC2 - Help setting up security based on how my software works

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

I'm currently developing on a project of mine where I need some guidance on securing my server.

My server is Ubuntu Server 64bit hosted at Amazon AWS EC2.
I have my own software running on it.

My problem is, I need to have all ports open and allow any IP to connect to it through my software.

My software is taking in data which is translated to text and send to another server and that other server is sending back data and that is send to the client.

My software is running on the standard ubuntu account I got with the server.
I've set up SSH on the server aswell so I can control it remotely.

My concern is,
If its easy to bypass my software and take control of the server.
Bad security.

Any advice, guidance, tips / tricks, firewall setup is more than welcome :)

Regards Kim

Comment: I fear that this is impossibly broad.  You should apply the principle of least privilege, but beyond this, it is impossible to cover all the fundamentals of security in this context.  Consider hiring a consultant.

Comment: I see, I've tried to narrow down the question. I've also found a guide about "least privilege" which I will read and see if I can apply the method. I cannot afford a consultant at the moment since I'm a student studying computer science. I was thinking, since any IP is allowed to connect and any port is open, would any attacker be able to take control of the server?

Comment: What ports/protocols does your application need to have open to the Internet to function? There's no way your application is using all 65,000 ports. What ports is you application listening on? For example, if you're running a web application, you only need to make TCP ports 80 and 443 accessible to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply get customers to register their IP address and have that attached to their account, thus giving you a nice whitelist.

Comment: My costumers might have a dynamic IP and they should be able to use the software nomatter where they are, even on public WIFI's and so on.

Comment: You should probably mention those sort of details in your question. You're not making it easy to secure things are you :p

Comment: I did say the costumers would connect to my EC2 through websocket which means their own IP, in that case there is a high chance that some costumers might have dynamic IP's :)

But I didnt mention they should able to connect through a public WIFI, to update my main question, the costumer should be able to connect to their account from wherever they are, like a normal website they log into :)

Comment: Once the user connects you could send an authorization to the user's email, and they can click the link in the email to authorize their current IP. This way users can connect from anywhere, and you have a neat way to keep most out traffic. it's not a fool proof solution but it's a nice start.

Comment: Good idea but it would be very annoying for the costumer to check their mail everytime they log in, therefor I look for security measures I can put onto the server, ubuntu accunt setup, permissions, firewall settings.